# How to fix error By in-app parameter in Sentry

Tags: axios, electron, sentry

My question is on a Sentry integration in an electronjs app.

We have some errors in Sentry that show a warning: 'Source code was not found'

Which usually means that source code mapping is not properly set. So I read the doc and made sure that our source code maps are properly set. Which is the case in my opinion.

Still according to the doc, I installed `sentry-cli` and run this command:
`sentry-cli sourcemaps explain ec9d14e80e464fe49fb917a5d383cc61 --org outmind`

Which return:

```
✔ Fetched data for event: bec1792b5c8048ce9663f35d07936369
✔ Event has release name: desktop@3.29.29
✔ Event has a valid exception present
✔ Event has a valid stacktrace present
✖ Event exception stacktrace has no in_app frames
```

And I do have a warning on the sentry page:
`X By in-app` with a hover: `Non contributing variant: exception of system take precedence`

Most of this scenario happen on `axios` call that return `401` errors - which is expected.

And I have absolutely no idea what's the issue here or what I'm supposed to do... Send a mail to the support, didn't get any answers.

Any suggestion on what I'm supposed to fix is welcome,

Thanks all